# Default kSecAttrAccessible value for keychain items?

Tags: objective-c, security, ios, keychain

Does anyone know the default value of the `kSecAttrAccessible` attribute for iOS keychain items (see [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services))? I'm just now upgrading an app to use stricter security, and I'm curious about how accessible my old keychain items–which didn't specify the `kSecAttrAccessible` key-value pair–are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: As of a few years ago, the default is now `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`.

According to the Session 209 (Securing Application Data) video from last year's WWDC, the existing data defaults to `kSecAttrAccessibleAlways` (so you'll need to update the accessibility class as necessary).

Comment: this might have changed in iOS6, I had to explicitly set it to `kSecAttrAccessibleAlways`in order to get this behavior

Comment: I agree with Erik's answer in that it's best to be explicit about what you want.

Comment: `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked` is now the default, and probably was a while ago.

Comment: Yeah I think it changed a couple of years ago. Not sure of the exact year. I’ll edit!

Answer (score 16):

I've just tested this on iOS 5.1 and 6.0, the default is now `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`.

However, I think it is always better to set an explicit `kSecAttrAccessible`, rather than relying on defaults to be secure enough for you.

Answer (score 10):

I've tested this on IOS 8.1 and default value is     **kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked**.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessiblewhenunlocked?language=objc) says:

> This is the default value for keychain items added without explicitly
>   setting an accessibility constant.